# Requesting and injecting Angular 2 components not known at bootstrap

Tags: angular

How to inject additional components, not known at bootstrap, into an angular 2 app after bootstrapping?

I am building an application that basically let's a user subscribe to certain products (3rd-party SPAs). In the left menu you see the topics you're subscribed to, on the right you view the apps in the main window. Each user can be subscribed to a different set of apps, which means that each user will have to bootstrap a user-specific set of components.

I have seen articles on **lazy loading** (https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.wv914275u), **dynamically loading components** (https://medium.com/@tudorgergely/injecting-components-dynamically-in-angular-2-3d36594d49a0#.eq1ybok65) and **providing external data at bootstrap** (https://blog.sstorie.com/providing-external-data-when-bootstrapping-angular-2/).

But none of these things seem to cover what I would actually want:

1. Bootstrap the main architecture of the app (a light skeleton that is true for every user)
2. Request from my web API the user's list of subscriptions; to build the menu (and routing!) dynamically, and to...
3. Request--after bootstrapping--the additional components (e.g. one javascript file per app) that should be available to him; some sort of pre-loading/lazy loading, but *without the app knowing at bootstrap what will be lazy-loaded in the future*.
4. 'Parsing' these files and making them available to (injecting in) the skeleton.

Can anybody help me with how to make this work, or advise me on how this should be done/done differently?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I'm in need exactly like the one you asked.

Comment: No, unfortunately not... Right now for me it is not key, but I would definitely be interested in a solution... I have lazy loading working, a modal component injector service, ... But each want to know at least the component at bootstrap, whether it's rendered or not. Would be great to be able to insert anonymous components on the fly, basically like a modal, in the end you just hang it in a dom node. No reason I see why that should be known a priori at bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with you. As of now i'm thinking of multiple angular 2 app in the same view.

Comment: Quite hacky option ;)

Comment: Well, on second thought.. I guess the problem arises with the fact that your app is compiled in the browser, so ng2 wants to know what to compile beforehand.